# how install biocLite and ComplexHeatmap using R studio on macOS Sierra

Tags: r, failed-installation

I am running R studio (Anaconda) R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30).

Trying to install biocLite and got this error:

```
> source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  internet routines cannot be loaded
> biocLite()
Error in biocLite() : could not find function "biocLite"
```

Trying to install ComplexHeatmap, gives me the following error(with both http and https):

```
> source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  internet routines cannot be loaded
> biocLite("ComplexHeatmap")
Error in biocLite("ComplexHeatmap") : could not find function "biocLite"
```

How do I install biocLite and ComplexHeatmaps using R studio or mac terminal?

thanks

Comment: Seems related to this issue: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/4421. I'd suggest not using the Anaconda version.

Comment: @neilfws thanks that helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

this post partly worked for me:
https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/4421

briefly:

on mac terminal installed these three things:

`conda install -c r r-essentials`
                         (I am not sure if r-essentials was actually needed for this but it didn't harm)
                                                   `conda install libssh2`

```
 conda install krb5
```

(restart R studio, this is very essential to see changes)
to install biocLite:

Now in the R studio run these two:

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite()
```

However, "ComplexHeatmap" failed and gave these warnings:
Code:
    source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
    biocLite("ComplexHeatmap")

warnings:

```
There were 11 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages(pkgs = doing, lib = lib, ...) :
  installation of package ‘mclust’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages(pkgs = doing, lib = lib, ...) :
  installation of package ‘mvtnorm’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages(pkgs = doing, lib = lib, ...) :
  installation of package ‘robustbase’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages(pkgs = doing, lib = lib, ...) :
  installation of package ‘prabclus’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages(pkgs = doing, lib = lib, ...) :
  installation of package ‘fpc’ had non-zero exit status
6: In install.packages(pkgs = doing, lib = lib, ...) :
  installation of package ‘dendextend’ had non-zero exit status
7: In install.packages(pkgs = doing, lib = lib, ...) :
  installation of package ‘ComplexHeatmap’ had non-zero exit status
8: In install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l,  ... :
  installation of package ‘glmnet’ had non-zero exit status
9: In install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l,  ... :
  installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status
10: In install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l,  ... :
  installation of package ‘xts’ had non-zero exit status
11: In install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l,  ... :
  installation of package ‘TTR’ had non-zero exit status
```